# Pop up window in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a send message button and on clicking that I open a website in a new page which has a panel and has few  labels and a send button inside the panel. I want to make that panel a pop up on the same window and the source page should be in the background blurred. how to make a pop up in the same window. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit Modal Popup Extender:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Using this control, you can transform a regular `Panel`, so that it appears as a Popup on top of your other content.

---

Alternatively, jQuery offers a simple modal plugin:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Agree, the Ajax Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender will do the exact job that is requested, except for "blurring" the page behind.  You can do a dark background with transparency that is not clickable, but it is not blurred.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use jquery and ajax.

[Jquery UI has a dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) which you can use for this task. There's also [jquery tools by Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) which is another good one.

I've personally used [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html) without any problems in the past. It's pretty easy to use. It allows you to open a separate page inside the modal popup.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [Pretty Photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) library lately and have been happy with how it looks and how simple it is to setup. Support for iFrames makes it easy to load in a separate page in the popup.